# How to switch colors on Base Color Image Texture Node?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, image

I downloaded this Sci-Fi Drone from the internet and I want yellow and black color to switch places so that drone is mostly black with less yellow. Is that possible? Did I even correctly connected PBR textures?

Drone's color is from the Base Color Image Texture Node.

Drone and textures download link: https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/aircraft/other/sci-fi-camera-drone

Here's my Material Setup.
[image]

Any kind of help is appreciated! Thanks!

My blend file: [image]

This is how the drone should look. It differs a little bit of mine because there's no reflection in the front part.

[image]

Comment: perhaps it is as simple as switching the threads of a Mix Shader, but please show your Shader Editor

Comment: @moonboots  Here you go.

Comment: it would be more efficient to share a blend file with material and texture (without the model if you don't want to share it). You can upload the file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ make sure the textures are packed in.

Comment: @lemon Thank you for the advice! Will do.

Comment: @DinoGržinić, the textures are not here it seems. Pack them in or the file is useless... Menu File/External data/Pack all..

Comment: @lemon project file size is too big (64mb and 30 is max)

Comment: @DinoGržinić so post a screen of color (Dif) texture (or link to original download link if it is free), to just see what colors are used in the texture, without it hard to advice something.

Comment: @lemon i did it

Answer (score 4):

### Material Nodes

For switching simple image you can try something like this ...

[image]

[image]

---

### **Compositor Nodes**

But for your texture would be better use Compositor with some Matte nodes to extract colors more accurately (or use any other image editor that supports color selection).

[image]

**Yellow-Braun**

- separate color by Matte node, Desaturate, Invert, ColorRamp to adjust final black color

**Grey**

- separate color by Matte node, Invert, RGB Curves or Color Mix node to make it yellow

After that, mix them together with Alpha Over node on top of original image where are stored Blue Black and red parts of texture. Save and use as texture in material.

version 01
[image]

version 02
[image]

[image]

Notes:

- To get more freedom in adjustments could be better assign material to different parts of the mesh as unique material (with the same textures). Like that you can easier to let rid of yellow lines on black surfaces just without need to mask texture since material is assign just to that part and not the others.
- Anyway I highly recommend to use some image editor than node system. In Photoshop could be done with masked yellow-braun layer, and grey layer, recolored above original, just in a few minutes. Only two layers, each with just two adjustment layers. And easily adjust mask manually for some details if needed.

Comment: Do you know if all my nodes are correctly connected?

Comment: I don't have a time now, but there was an PBR add-on which allows you to add selected images and automatically to connect. I cant find it so in mean time check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dj5LegtOyyI or this add-on https://github.com/jensnt/pbr-material-importer